# possibility of python packages without __init__.py

Tags: python

Is it possible to make python packages without `__init__.py` in directory(python 2)?The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) talks nothing about this topic.

Comment: Before Python 3.3, you can not do it.

Comment: oh yes i see the point.thx